# How to delete some part of string from existing string in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

Main string contains (input string)

"Success: 173.256.9.83"

and output string should contain

"173.256.9.83"

please explain with code in obejctive c

Comment: This is so clearly explained in the documentation. Have you seen it? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: What have you tried..!
First google and then post..any question...!@pritu3716

Answer (score 2):

```
[@"Success: 173.256.9.83" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"Success: " withString:@""];
```

or you can substring the string if `Success:` always at the beginning of the string:

```
[@"Success: 173.256.9.83" substringFromIndex: 9];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
NSString *aStrOut = [aStr substringFromIndex:[aStr rangeOfString:@" " options:NSBackwardsSearch].location + 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to separate it into two strings by colonspace(@": ") or colon (:) or space (@" ")then store them into array and you can get second/last object of array to get address text.

```
NSArray *seperatedArray=[mainString componentsSeperatedByString:@": "];//or u can use @" "

self.yourLabel.text=[seperatedArray objectAtIndex:1];
```

Hope it helps you..!

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear:

```
//your original string
NSString *originalString = @"Success: 173.256.9.83";

//seperating the originalString into 2 strings using ": "
NSArray *seperatorArray = [originalString componentsSeperatedByString:@": "];
NSString *outputString = [seperatorArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Output:

> 173.256.9.83

Comment: I think you need to use the second object in the array? objectAtIndex:1